# Binary Homology Theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I've found a [proof of Euler's formula by using binary homology](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/binary.html). Does Binary Homology Theory really exist? If yes, could someone please give some reference for an introductory treatment of this?

Comment: Do you already know about "homology" in general (without the qualifier "binary", which simply means "mod 2" here)?

Comment: Unfortunately, not too much. It seems very complicated to me, but this treatment with a vector space of subsets with symmetric difference is very attractive to me But I don't know how is it related to the "real" homology theories. I didn't see this in any algebraic geometry book. And I also don't know what is the meaning of "homology over some field".

Comment: It might be a good idea to learn some algebraic topology then. Hatcher's book *Algebraic Topology* is a commonly cited reference, and you can find alternatives [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84409/best-algebraic-topology-book-alternative-to-allen-hatcher-free-book).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that binary homology means homology over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In that case I recommend Hausmann's "Mod Two Homology and Cohomology".

Comment: Yes I thought of this. The book is available on-line [here](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/hausmann/booPrepubl.html)